# calculate days excluding weekends and public holidays in sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How do I exclude weekends(sat and sun) and public holidays when counting number of days between a start and end time in sharepoint 2010 calculate column.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude weekends like this in the calculated column:

```
=IF(AND((WEEKDAY(EndDate,2))<(WEEKDAY(StartDate,2)),((WEEKDAY(StartDate,2))-(WEEKDAY(EndDate,2)))>1),(((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)))
```

I don't know how about public holidays :)